# How would you resolve a naming conflict inside dart?

Tags: dart

Does dart have some sort of alias for naming conflicts like this?

```dart
library flutterfly;

import 'dart:ui';

class Color {
  Color._();
  
  // Color should be the class from dart:ui instead of itself.
  static Color white() {
    return Color(#FFFFFFFF);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Import the library with a namespace/prefix](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#specifying-a-library-prefix):

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class Color {
  Color._();

  static ui.Color white() {
    return ui.Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
  }
}
```

That said, because whoever imports your `flutterfly` library can choose  whatever library prefix they want (if any), adding your own `Color` class to use as a namespace isn't very useful, and its presence likely would cause conflicts for anything that uses it.  Effective Dart recommends [against classes that contain only static members](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members).  For this example, you could use top-level functions instead.