# Consumer is not a function

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to access my provider, but while wrapping my widget with consumer widget, but it is throwing compilation error as below:

```
'Consumer' isn't a function.
Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named 'Consumer'.dartinvocation_of_non_function
The name 'Consumer' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter_riverpod/src/consumer.dart (via package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart)' and 'package:provider/src/consumer.dart (via package:provider/provider.dart)'.
Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.d"
```

Here is the code:

```dart
Consumer(
  builder: (context, ref, child) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if(itemInCart)
        {  Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const NavigationScreen(
                    screenIndex: 3,
                  ),
                ),
              );
        }else{
              addToCart(widget.product);
        ref.read(NavigationScreenState.itemCountProvider.notifier).state++;
            
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 120,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          color: AppConstants.secondaryColor,
          border: Border.all(
              // color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 232, 65, 107),
              ),
        ),
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            itemInCart == false ? 'Add To Cart' : 'Go To Cart',
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          // child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
),
```

even if I try to extend the widget state with consumerstate... I am getting this

```
'_DetailsContainerState.build' ('Widget Function(BuildContext, WidgetRef, Widget?)') isn't a valid override of 'State.build' ('Widget Function(BuildContext)').dartinvalid_override
framework.dart(1457, 10): The member being overridden.
Widget build(
  BuildContext context,
  WidgetRef ref,
  Widget? child,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `flutter_riverpod` and `provider`, in which both of them have a `Consumer` class. If you want to use `Consumer` from `flutter_riverpod`, hide the `Consumer` class from the `provider` import.

```dart
import 'package:provider/provider.dart' hide Consumer;
```

You can also hide multiple identifiers, so do this for every conflicting imports. For example:

```dart
import 'package:example_package/example_package.dart' hide ClassA, ClassB, methodA;
```

---

If you want to use `ConsumerState`, make sure you also change the `StatefulWidget` to `ConsumerStatefulWidget`.

---

See also:

- [Importing only part of a library](https://dart.dev/language/libraries#importing-only-part-of-a-library)
- [How would you resolve a naming conflict inside dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66937190/how-would-you-resolve-a-naming-conflict-inside-dart)